# Distance between intersections on a given curve in polar form is constant

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates

> A straight line through the origin intersects the curve $C_1: r=1+\cos(t),\, 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$ at two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ outside of the origin. Show that the distance between $P_1$ and $P_2$ is $2$.

How do I go about solving this problem? All I can think of is having $P_1=(0,0)$ and $P_2=(0,2)$ but if I understand the description of this question correctly then this isn't valid. Anyone know how to go about this one?

Comment: The first thing to do is figure out what kind of curve $C_1$ is. (For one thing, it's not a circle or an ellipse.) If you can get it in Cartesian form, great; otherwise, sketch/plot it.

Comment: its a standard cardoid since its on the form: a+-acos(t) or a+-asin(t) @Semiclassical

Comment: Right, e.g. the figure [here](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Curves/Cardioid.html). Note that if you put a line at an angle angle through the origin, it'll pass through the cardioid twice (not including the origin). You're looking for the distance between those two points.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A line passing through the origin at an angle of $\theta_0$ is described in polar form as those points with $r>0$ and either $\theta=\theta_0$ or $\theta=\theta_0+\pi$.

Comment: I dont really understand how to use this on this problem

Comment: @dfge34 Suppose you have a point on the curve, with polar coordinates $(r(\theta_0),\theta_0)$. By definition, this point is found on the line making an angle of $\theta_0$ with the positive $x$-axis and is a distance $r=1-\cos\theta_0$ away. If you then increase the angle by $\pi$, you'll be on the same line as before but now on the opposite side of the origin. Now consider what $r$ would have to be if you're again on the curve.

Comment: hmm im not about what you mean with opposite side of the origin but I understand that the distance between two points P1 and P2 is 2 if you just add another pi to the angle considering the function is 1+cos(thetha).

Comment: Right. So one point will be a distance $1-\cos\theta$ from the origin, the other $1+\cos\theta$. But if they both lie on the same line through the origin, what does that tell you about their separation?